# No breadcrumbs with MVCSiteMapProvider custom MvcRouteHandler

Tags: breadcrumbs, sitemapprovider, sitemappath

I have 2 routes in global.asax

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultFriendlyUrl",
            "Page/{FriendlyUrl}",
            null,
            new string[] { "MvcApplication2.Controllers" }
        ).RouteHandler = new FriendlyUrlRouteHandler();


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "MvcApplication2.Controllers" }
        );
```

so, FriendlyUrlRouteHandler work all my /Page/blablabla routes and send to PageController with 1 action Index

```
public class FriendlyUrlRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var friendlyUrl = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["FriendlyUrl"];

        PageItem page = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(friendlyUrl))
            page = PageManager.GetPageByFriendlyUrl(friendlyUrl);

        if (page == null)
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "home";
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "index";
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] = null;
        }
        else
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "page";
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "index";
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] = page.PageID;
        }

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Then PageController get content for my page and show it. But MvcSiteMapProvider don't show breadcrumbs for these pages

SiteMap.cs

```
public class SiteMap : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
    {
        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();
        returnValue.Add(new DynamicNode() { Key = "id1", Title="CustomPage", Controller="Page", Action="Index" });
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

And my CustomPage doesn,t exists in @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath(), but page is showed correctly. What,s wrong in my code?
So I can,t build tree of my custom pages in breadcrumbs string...

Answer (score 1):

Please provide your Mvc.sitemap.

Your instance of DynamicNode appears to be missing the ParentKey.